extract variables from list and run a loop
I have a scenario like below in Python.
contents of run_main.py are below
system_code = 'Ind'

if system_code == 'Ind':
    ft_tb = ['B_FT', 'S_FT', 'D_FT']
    bt_tb = ['B_BT', 'S_BT', 'D_BT']
else:
    ft_tb = ['T_FT', 'T_FT', 'T_FT']
    bt_tb = ['T_BT', 'T_BT', 'T_BT']

Now I want to run below code in loop for each list based on system_code
for example:
if system_code == Ind
    
    # ft_tb list
    element_1, element_2, element_3 = ft_tb[:3]
    
    print("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE application = {}".format(element_1, element_3))
    print("DELETE FROM {} WHERE application = {}".format(element_2, element_3))
            
    # bt_tb list
    element_1, element_2, element_3 = bt_tb[:3]

    print("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE application = {}".format(element_1, element_3))
    print("DELETE FROM {} WHERE application = {}".format(element_2, element_3))
    

        


In the second code, is Ind really supposed to be a variable? Why do you need the second if statement, when you already set the variables in the first one?

If you want to run a loop, make a list that you can iterate over instead of using separate variables.

Don't use formatting to substitute values into the WHERE clause, use a prepared statement with parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

@Barmar yes Ind is a variable

Then why did you add quotes in the last edit?

@Barmar sorry got confused.

You are mixing code with expected output in the same code block, that's confusing.

@mkrieger1 Removed the output part

Okay, and now it's not clear what your question is from the contents of your post.

Use a list instead of multiple variables, then you can iterate over it.
if system_code == 'Ind':
    sql_params = [
        {'select_tbl': 'B_FT', 'delete_tbl': 'S_FT', 'app': 'D_FT'},
        {'select_tbl': 'B_BT', 'delete_tbl': 'S_BT', 'app': 'D_BT'}
    ]
else:
    sql_params = [
        {'select_tbl': 'T_FT', 'delete_tbl': 'T_FT', 'app': 'T_FT'},
        {'select_tbl': 'T_BT', 'delete_tbl': 'T_BT', 'app': 'T_BT'}
    ]

if system_code == Ind:
    for p in sql_params:
        print(f"SELECT * FROM {p['select_tbl']} WHERE application = '{p['app']}'")
        print(f"DELETE * FROM {p['delete_tbl']} WHERE application = '{p['app']}'")


It is working fine thank you. Just a small code correction. {p['select_tbl'}  it is missing parenthesis
